# RSA: Get exponent and modulus given a public key

Tags: openssl, rsa, public-key

I need to encrypt some data using RSA in JavaScript. All of the libraries around ask for an exponent and a modulus, yet I get a single `public.key` file from my opponent.

How do you retrieve the public `exponent` and `modulus` part from an RSA file?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this yet?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

It depends on the tools you can use. I doubt there is a JavaScript too that could do it directly within the browser. It also depends if it's a one-off (always the same key) or whether you need to script it.

### Command-line / OpenSSL

If you want to use something like OpenSSL on a unix command line, you can do something as follows.
I'm assuming you public.key file contains something like this:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAmBAjFv+29CaiQqYZIw4P
J0q5Qz2gS7kbGleS3ai8Xbhu5n8PLomldxbRz0RpdCuxqd1yvaicqpDKe/TT09sR
mL1h8Sx3Qa3EQmqI0TcEEqk27Ak0DTFxuVrq7c5hHB5fbJ4o7iEq5MYfdSl4pZax
UxdNv4jRElymdap8/iOo3SU1RsaK6y7kox1/tm2cfWZZhMlRFYJnpoXpyNYrp+Yo
CNKxmZJnMsS698kaFjDlyznLlihwMroY0mQvdD7dCeBoVlfPUGPAlamwWyqtIU+9
5xVkSp3kxcNcNb/mePSKQIPafQ1sAmBKPwycA/1I5nLzDVuQa95ZWMn0JkphtFIh
HQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Then, the commands would be:

```
PUBKEY=`grep -v -- ----- public.key | tr -d '\n'`
```

Then, you can look into the ASN.1 structure:

```
echo $PUBKEY | base64 -d | openssl asn1parse -inform DER -i
```

This should give you something like this:

```
    0:d=0  hl=4 l= 290 cons: SEQUENCE          
    4:d=1  hl=2 l=  13 cons:  SEQUENCE          
    6:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim:   OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
   17:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim:   NULL              
   19:d=1  hl=4 l= 271 prim:  BIT STRING
```

The modulus and public exponent are in the last BIT STRING, offset 19, so use `-strparse`:

```
 echo $PUBKEY | base64 -d | openssl asn1parse -inform DER -i -strparse 19
```

This will give you the modulus and the public exponent, in hexadecimal (the two INTEGERs):

```
    0:d=0  hl=4 l= 266 cons: SEQUENCE          
    4:d=1  hl=4 l= 257 prim:  INTEGER           :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
  265:d=1  hl=2 l=   3 prim:  INTEGER           :010001
```

That's probably fine if it's always the same key, but this is probably not very convenient to put in a script.

Alternatively (and this might be easier to put into a script),

```
openssl rsa -pubin -inform PEM -text -noout < public.key
```

will return this:

```
Modulus (2048 bit):
    00:98:10:23:16:ff:b6:f4:26:a2:42:a6:19:23:0e:
    0f:27:4a:b9:43:3d:a0:4b:b9:1b:1a:57:92:dd:a8:
    bc:5d:b8:6e:e6:7f:0f:2e:89:a5:77:16:d1:cf:44:
    69:74:2b:b1:a9:dd:72:bd:a8:9c:aa:90:ca:7b:f4:
    d3:d3:db:11:98:bd:61:f1:2c:77:41:ad:c4:42:6a:
    88:d1:37:04:12:a9:36:ec:09:34:0d:31:71:b9:5a:
    ea:ed:ce:61:1c:1e:5f:6c:9e:28:ee:21:2a:e4:c6:
    1f:75:29:78:a5:96:b1:53:17:4d:bf:88:d1:12:5c:
    a6:75:aa:7c:fe:23:a8:dd:25:35:46:c6:8a:eb:2e:
    e4:a3:1d:7f:b6:6d:9c:7d:66:59:84:c9:51:15:82:
    67:a6:85:e9:c8:d6:2b:a7:e6:28:08:d2:b1:99:92:
    67:32:c4:ba:f7:c9:1a:16:30:e5:cb:39:cb:96:28:
    70:32:ba:18:d2:64:2f:74:3e:dd:09:e0:68:56:57:
    cf:50:63:c0:95:a9:b0:5b:2a:ad:21:4f:bd:e7:15:
    64:4a:9d:e4:c5:c3:5c:35:bf:e6:78:f4:8a:40:83:
    da:7d:0d:6c:02:60:4a:3f:0c:9c:03:fd:48:e6:72:
    f3:0d:5b:90:6b:de:59:58:c9:f4:26:4a:61:b4:52:
    21:1d
Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
```

### Java

It depends on the input format. If it's an X.509 certificate in a keystore, use `(RSAPublicKey)cert.getPublicKey()`: this object has two getters for the modulus and the exponent.

If it's in the format as above, you might want to use [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) and its `PEMReader` to read it. I haven't tried the following code, but this would look more or less like this:

```
PEMReader pemReader = new PEMReader(new FileReader("file.pem"));
Object obj = pemReader.readObject();
pemReader.close();
if (obj instanceof X509Certificate) {
   // Just in case your file contains in fact an X.509 certificate,
   // useless otherwise.
   obj = ((X509Certificate)obj).getPublicKey();
}
if (obj instanceof RSAPublicKey) {
   // ... use the getters to get the BigIntegers.
}
```

(You can use BouncyCastle similarly in C# too.)

Comment: +1 Nice answer. Looking at the source code for PEMReader.java, it is a real workhorse. It will detect and read in all kinds of variants and return an appropriate object. Another possible format is the X509EncodedKeySpec, which is returned by RSAPublicKey.getEncoded() in java

Comment: RSAPublicKey.getEncoded() (even with the Sun provider implementation) will return an array of byte[], which is the same content as what's between --BEGIN/END PUBLIC KEY-- in the PEM format, except that it's base64-encoded for text rendering there. Indeed, you could use X509EncodedKeySpec without BouncyCastle, but you would have to do the base64 decoding and then use the java.security.KeyFactory for build the actual RSAPublicKey. It's feasible, but I prefer to use BC.

Comment: Thank you very much Bruno. I will go with the commandline version…

Comment: can you do similar things to private key? get the exponent? Thanks!

Comment: You can use forge to do RSA in JS... it doesn't require you to parse out the exponent and modulus (but you can if you want to): https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge#rsa

Comment: (1) you don't need to decode PEM yourself for `openssl asn1parse`, it can handle PEM (and that's even the default); it can even handle a PEM _body_ (base64 of DER with linebreaks, but no BEGIN/END lines). Just don't include any 'comments' _outside_ the PEM block; many other `openssl` commands can handle that, but not `asn1parse` (2) BouncyCastle since 1.47 in 2012 has PEMReader in `bcpkix` not `bcprov` and since 1.50 in 2013 it is renamed PEMParser; for a certificate it returns `X509CertificateHolder` not `X509Certificate` and for publickey it returns `SubjectPublicKeyInfo`

Answer (score 38):

Beware the leading 00 that can appear in the modulus when using:

```
openssl rsa -pubin -inform PEM -text -noout < public.key
```

The example modulus contains 257 bytes rather than 256 bytes because of that 00, which is included because the 9 in 98 looks like a negative signed number.

Answer (score 6):

Mostly for my own reference, here's how you get it from a private key generated by ssh-keygen

```
openssl rsa -text -noout -in ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Of course, this only works with the private key.

Comment: Not for private keys generated by `ssh-keygen -o` since 6.5 in 2014, or by default (without `-m pem`) since 7.8 in 2018; those use an OpenSSH-proprietary format `openssl` can't read. OpenSSH's `id_xxx.pub` is also unreadable by OpenSSL but `ssh-keygen -e -m pkcs8` since about 6.0 outputs a PEM public key readable by `openssl rsa -pubin -text -noout` (as in Bruno's long-ago answer)

Answer (score 4):

you can directly print modulus by

```
openssl rsa -pubin -in public_key.pem -noout -modulus
```

Bonus: add " | openssl md5" at the end to get a smaller string to compare easily

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the above answers, we can use `asn1parse` to get the values

```
$ openssl asn1parse -i -in pub0.der -inform DER -offset 24
0:d=0  hl=4 l= 266 cons: SEQUENCE
4:d=1  hl=4 l= 257 prim:  INTEGER           :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
265:d=1  hl=2 l= 3 prim:  INTEGER           :010001
```

Now, to get to this offset,we try the default asn1parse

```
$ openssl asn1parse -i -in pub0.der -inform DER
 0:d=0  hl=4 l= 290 cons: SEQUENCE
 4:d=1  hl=2 l=  13 cons:  SEQUENCE
 6:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim:   OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
17:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim:   NULL
19:d=1  hl=4 l= 271 prim:  BIT STRING
```

We need to get to the BIT String part, so we add the sizes

`depth_0_header(4) + depth_1_full_size(2 + 13) + Container_1_EOC_bit + BIT_STRING_header(4) = 24`

This can be better visialized at: [ASN.1 Parser](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAyRMUMMzpxC9lliO9xzp4MCmiPkuj-vdP489FL52p2vKdb0ZVbkI_sCYQvE-E4Z-HMz6tC7OzkKPvp_s5LpNQZdgKJ1iaIcoFH6ImGVIW2KOfFRvQM0llVRdEVmrT2utT66J3g64IuqrKQGwn7YvmFFGMjNfRS756_r4djQM3Ta57dWTPEYKns7oRXNlBariZxYAziO5m-jZ2dQp3rIcO2gJ9yV5XubToZKPJjxupmkcmwIUXjqj8bFSb5e35cMy42Pmu3uP1z95XQyfQXtBAYLJSX7ZxHx14JU_1kIkZmJKp7MfU5JUODNIkbh5hOIlyLXPbVrJOV_OUPhFSB3a8TwIDAQAB), if you hover at tags, you will see the offsets

Another amazing resource: [Microsoft's ASN.1 Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/SecCertEnroll/about-sequence)

Answer (score 2):

If you need to parse ASN.1 objects in script, there's a library for that: https://github.com/lapo-luchini/asn1js

For doing the math, I found jsbn convenient: http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/

Walking the ASN.1 structure and extracting the exp/mod/subject/etc. is up to you -- I never got that far!

Answer (score 0):

I manage to find the answer for this [solution](https://www.npmjs.com/package/asn1-parser?activeTab=readme), have to do javascript injection for this to install atob

```
const atob:any = require('atob');
asn1(pem: any){
      asn1parser.Enc.base64ToBuf = function (b64:any) {
    return asn1parser.Enc.binToBuf(atob(b64));
  };
  const dertest = asn1parser.PEM.parseBlock(pem).der;
   var hex = asn1parser.Enc.bufToHex(asn1parser.PEM.parseBlock(pem).der)
   var buf = asn1parser.ASN1.parse(dertest);
  var asn1 = JSON.stringify(asn1parser.ASN1.parse(dertest), asn1parser.ASN1._replacer, 2 );
```