# How to find the modulus and exponent from a public key?

Tags: php, cryptography, public-key, modulus

I need to encrypt some data using RSA in PHP. All of the libraries around ask for an exponent and a modulus, yet I get a single public key like this

Public Key:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDVnXLu0FM37CmUYjJuu4JaB6bo
liJ1b5BybAVcqlfvUxjpU+VVhKnZNd4IU7S0ITRTAKvoFk68CiUmaRA9871mfxjp
sX6YeNs913LyGwFw0bmno+1o6URBui2p3gHwGQL8R/jIl4NHC1TF47Q5Vj3RuraV
Ky4YH6dp7YIJRaU7JQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

How do you retrieve the public exponent and modulus part from this ?

Comment: This is a near duplicate of [RSA: Get exponent and modulus given a public key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116907/rsa-get-exponent-and-modulus-given-a-public-key)

Comment: @conspicuous near, but not exactly, since PHP might have different mechanisms for doing the same job.

Comment: What "all of the libraries" did you try? For me more natural way is to accept RSA key in PKCS#1.5 format (and what you have is a wrapped and base64-encoded form of PKCS#1.5 as it seems).

Comment: Have you tried [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/documentation/misc_crypt.html#misc_crypt_rsa_format)

Answer (score 2):

How'd you get that key?

```
openssl asn1parse -inform PEM -in pubkey.txt -i
    0:d=0  hl=3 l= 159 cons: SEQUENCE
    3:d=1  hl=2 l=  13 cons:  SEQUENCE
    5:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim:   OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
   16:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim:   NULL
   18:d=1  hl=3 l= 141 prim:  BIT STRING
```

According to that the last sequence of bytes should have a length of 141 and yet the whole key is only 119 characters long.

Ignoring how long the BIT STRING ought to be, for the moment, not even it appears to conform to any standard format.