# Export a certificate in asn.1 notation from X509Certificate2

Tags: .net, cryptography, certificate, asn.1, der

I'm currently learning working with certificates and now I'm curious, if it is possible to get the ASN.1 notation of a loaded certificate from a `X509Certificate2`-instance.

I have found the `Export`-Method and it works fine, however I have not seen a possibilty to change the encoding of the output format - it's only in the DER-format.

Is there a possibility to export/convert a loaded certificate as an ASCII ASN.1 certificate, something like in the example below:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 1 (0x1)
        Signature Algorithm: md5WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=XY....
 ...
```

Or is there a converter to convert DER to plain text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a Gtk# tool (in C#) to do this a few years ago. The full source code is available from https://github.com/mono/mono-tools/tree/master/asn1view

You likely need only [common/PrettyPrinter.cs](https://github.com/mono/mono-tools/blob/master/asn1view/common/PrettyPrinter.cs) and [common/ASN1Decoder.cs](https://github.com/mono/mono-tools/blob/master/asn1view/common/ASN1Decoder.cs) unless you want pretty names for OIDs.

**EDIT**: The above is a bit lower-level than X.509 certificates - but it will work for X.509 CRL and other structures you know (or not) that can be embedded into the certificates/crl.

Comment: +1 Great! Thank you! Do you have a code block that defines already some common used OIDs for the OidCache-class?

Comment: No, it was fully on demand, i.e. retrieved/cached as required. OTOH you could build a pre-cache from running that code on several certificates and ship this as default.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on whether you need to do this within .Net, you may be interested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116907/rsa-get-exponent-and-modulus-given-a-public-key/3117100#3117100) (`openssl asn1parse`, using the DER file you've exported).

If you need to do this within .Net, you should be able to use [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/).

Comment: Or maybe just `openssl x509 -text -noout -in <certfile>` is what he wants?

Comment: @GregS - That worked great, except I had to add '-inform DER' as well. You should put that as an answer!