# Convert DER-encoded data to text in c#

Tags: .net, encoding, der

I have opened [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929443/export-a-certificate-in-asn-1-notation-from-x509certificate2) on how to save certificate data as human readable ASN.1-text.

But maybe this question is to specific and i would have better asked more generalized:

Is there a converter for converting DER-encoded data into plain text in .net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [ASN.1-converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929443/export-a-certificate-in-asn-1-notation-from-x509certificate2/7935940#7935940) from [poupou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/220643/poupou).