# RSA Public Key format

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

Where can i find some documentation on the format of an RSA public key?

An RSA public key formatted by `OpenSSH`:

> ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQB/nAmOjTmezNUDKYvEeIRf2YnwM9/uUG1d0BYsc8/tRtx+RGi7N2lUbp728MXGwdnL9od4cItzky/zVdLZE2cycOa18xBK9cOWmcKS0A8FYBxEQWJ/q9YVUgZbFKfYGaGQxsER+A0w/fX8ALuk78ktP31K69LcQgxIsl7rNzxsoOQKJ/CIxOGMMxczYTiEoLvQhapFQMs3FL96didKr/QbrfB1WT6s3838SEaXfgZvLef1YB2xmfhbT9OXFE3FXvh2UPBfN+ffE7iiayQf/2XR+8j4N4bW30DiPtOQLGUrH1y5X/rpNZNlWW2+jGIxqZtgWg7lTy3mXy5x836Sj/6L

The same public key formatted for use in Secure Shell [(RFC 4716 - The Secure Shell (SSH) Public Key File Format)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4716):

```
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQB/nAmOjTmezNUDKYvEeIRf2YnwM9/uUG1d0BYs
c8/tRtx+RGi7N2lUbp728MXGwdnL9od4cItzky/zVdLZE2cycOa18xBK9cOWmcKS
0A8FYBxEQWJ/q9YVUgZbFKfYGaGQxsER+A0w/fX8ALuk78ktP31K69LcQgxIsl7r
NzxsoOQKJ/CIxOGMMxczYTiEoLvQhapFQMs3FL96didKr/QbrfB1WT6s3838SEaX
fgZvLef1YB2xmfhbT9OXFE3FXvh2UPBfN+ffE7iiayQf/2XR+8j4N4bW30DiPtOQ
LGUrH1y5X/rpNZNlWW2+jGIxqZtgWg7lTy3mXy5x836Sj/6L
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
```

The same public key formatted as an RSA public key (note the *five* **`-`**, and no space):

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBCgKCAQEA+xGZ/wcz9ugFpP07Nspo6U17l0YhFiFpxxU4pTk3Lifz9R3zsIsu
ERwta7+fWIfxOo208ett/jhskiVodSEt3QBGh4XBipyWopKwZ93HHaDVZAALi/2A
+xTBtWdEo7XGUujKDvC2/aZKukfjpOiUI8AhLAfjmlcD/UZ1QPh0mHsglRNCmpCw
mwSXA9VNmhz+PiB+Dml4WWnKW/VHo2ujTXxq7+efMU4H2fny3Se3KYOsFPFGZ1TN
QSYlFuShWrHPtiLmUdPoP6CV2mML1tk+l7DIIqXrQhLUKDACeM5roMx0kLhUWB8P
+0uj1CNlNN4JRZlC7xFfqiMbFRU9Z4N6YwIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

The hex dump of the base-64 encoded data:

```
00 00 00 07 73 73 68 2d 72 73 61 00 00 00 01 25 00 00 01 00 7f 9c 09
8e 8d 39 9e cc d5 03 29 8b c4 78 84 5f d9 89 f0 33 df ee 50 6d 5d d0 
16 2c 73 cf ed 46 dc 7e 44 68 bb 37 69 54 6e 9e f6 f0 c5 c6 c1 d9 cb
f6 87 78 70 8b 73 93 2f f3 55 d2 d9 13 67 32 70 e6 b5 f3 10 4a f5 c3 
96 99 c2 92 d0 0f 05 60 1c 44 41 62 7f ab d6 15 52 06 5b 14 a7 d8 19 
a1 90 c6 c1 11 f8 0d 30 fd f5 fc 00 bb a4 ef c9 2d 3f 7d 4a eb d2 dc 
42 0c 48 b2 5e eb 37 3c 6c a0 e4 0a 27 f0 88 c4 e1 8c 33 17 33 61 38 
84 a0 bb d0 85 aa 45 40 cb 37 14 bf 7a 76 27 4a af f4 1b ad f0 75 59 
3e ac df cd fc 48 46 97 7e 06 6f 2d e7 f5 60 1d b1 99 f8 5b 4f d3 97 
14 4d c5 5e f8 76 50 f0 5f 37 e7 df 13 b8 a2 6b 24 1f ff 65 d1 fb c8 
f8 37 86 d6 df 40 e2 3e d3 90 2c 65 2b 1f 5c b9 5f fa e9 35 93 65 59 
6d be 8c 62 31 a9 9b 60 5a 0e e5 4f 2d e6 5f 2e 71 f3 7e 92 8f fe 8b
```

i've [read that there are a couple of formats](http://www.cryptosys.net/pki/rsakeyformats.html):

> Key data may be encoded in three general ways:
>
> - Binary DER-encoded format. This is sometimes called ASN.1 BER-encoded
> - PEM or base64 format. This is the same data as the DER-encoded file but it is encoded in base64 with additional header and footer lines
> - XML format.

If it's [ASN.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One), the hex certainly doesn't look like it.

What's the format of an RSA public key?

---

### See also

- [RSA Key Formats](http://www.cryptosys.net/pki/rsakeyformats.html)
- [Abstract Syntax Notation One](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One)
- [Convert Base64 Public Key to XML Signature](http://tools.ailon.org/tools/XmlKey)
- [Decode PEM formats](https://lapo.it/asn1js/)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can't just change the delimiters from `---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----` to `-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----` and expect that it will be sufficient to convert from one format to another (which is what you've done in your example).

[This article](http://blog.oddbit.com/2011/05/08/converting-openssh-public-keys) has a good explanation about both formats.

What you get in an `RSA PUBLIC KEY` is closer to the content of a `PUBLIC KEY`, but you need to offset the start of your ASN.1 structure to reflect the fact that `PUBLIC KEY` also has an indicator saying which type of key it is (see [RFC 3447](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#appendix-A)). You can see this using `openssl asn1parse` and `-strparse 19`, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3117100/372643).

*EDIT*: Following your edit, your can get the details of your `RSA PUBLIC KEY` structure using `grep -v -- ----- | tr -d '\n' | base64 -d | openssl asn1parse -inform DER`:

```
    0:d=0  hl=4 l= 266 cons: SEQUENCE          
    4:d=1  hl=4 l= 257 prim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
  265:d=1  hl=2 l=   3 prim: INTEGER           :010001
```

To decode the SSH key format, you need to use the data format specification in [RFC 4251](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4251#section-5) too, in conjunction with RFC 4253:

> ```
>    The "ssh-rsa" key format has the following specific encoding:
>
>       string    "ssh-rsa"
>       mpint     e
>       mpint     n
> ```

For example, at the beginning, you get `00 00 00 07 73 73 68 2d 72 73 61`. The first four bytes (`00 00 00 07`) give you the length. The rest is the string itself: 73=s, 68=h, ... -> `73 73 68 2d 72 73 61`=`ssh-rsa`, followed by the exponent of length 1 (`00 00 00 01 25`) and the modulus of length 256 (`00 00 01 00 7f ...`).

Comment: [That article](http://blog.oddbit.com/2011/05/converting-openssh-public-keys.html) mentions that OpenSSH format *is* a format, but doesn't get into the details of the format. Instead it mentions that the format is fully documented in [RFC 4253 - The Secure Shell (SSH) Transport Layer Protocol - Section 6.6.  Public Key Algorithms](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4253#section-6.6); except i cannot find any documentation there. i updated the question to use someone's public RSA key i found.

Comment: I believe the first link has moved to http://blog.oddbit.com/2011/05/08/converting-openssh-public-keys/

Comment: You can use `openssl asn1parse -inform PEM` with `-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY----` data, or any other PEM structure. Much easier than trying to manually manipulate headers with grep / tr / base64 commands.

Answer (score 70):

Starting from the decoded base64 data of an **OpenSSL rsa-ssh Key**, i've been able to *guess* a format:

- `00 00 00 07`: four byte length prefix (7 bytes)
- `73 73 68 2d 72 73 61`: *"ssh-rsa"*
- `00 00 00 01`: four byte length prefix (1 byte)
- `25`: RSA Exponent (*`e`*): **25**
- `00 00 01 00`: four byte length prefix (256 bytes)
- RSA Modulus (*`n`*):

  ```
    7f 9c 09 8e 8d 39 9e cc d5 03 29 8b c4 78 84 5f
    d9 89 f0 33 df ee 50 6d 5d d0 16 2c 73 cf ed 46 
    dc 7e 44 68 bb 37 69 54 6e 9e f6 f0 c5 c6 c1 d9 
    cb f6 87 78 70 8b 73 93 2f f3 55 d2 d9 13 67 32 
    70 e6 b5 f3 10 4a f5 c3 96 99 c2 92 d0 0f 05 60 
    1c 44 41 62 7f ab d6 15 52 06 5b 14 a7 d8 19 a1 
    90 c6 c1 11 f8 0d 30 fd f5 fc 00 bb a4 ef c9 2d 
    3f 7d 4a eb d2 dc 42 0c 48 b2 5e eb 37 3c 6c a0 
    e4 0a 27 f0 88 c4 e1 8c 33 17 33 61 38 84 a0 bb 
    d0 85 aa 45 40 cb 37 14 bf 7a 76 27 4a af f4 1b 
    ad f0 75 59 3e ac df cd fc 48 46 97 7e 06 6f 2d 
    e7 f5 60 1d b1 99 f8 5b 4f d3 97 14 4d c5 5e f8 
    76 50 f0 5f 37 e7 df 13 b8 a2 6b 24 1f ff 65 d1 
    fb c8 f8 37 86 d6 df 40 e2 3e d3 90 2c 65 2b 1f 
    5c b9 5f fa e9 35 93 65 59 6d be 8c 62 31 a9 9b 
    60 5a 0e e5 4f 2d e6 5f 2e 71 f3 7e 92 8f fe 8b
  ```

The closest validation of my theory i can find it from RFC 4253:

> The "ssh-rsa" key format has the following specific encoding:
>
> ```
>   string    "ssh-rsa"
>   mpint     e
>   mpint     n
> ```
>
> Here the 'e' and 'n' parameters form the signature key blob.

But it doesn't explain the length prefixes.

---

Taking the random `RSA PUBLIC KEY` i found (in the question), and decoding the base64 into hex:

```
30 82 01 0a 02 82 01 01 00 fb 11 99 ff 07 33 f6 e8 05 a4 fd 3b 36 ca 68 
e9 4d 7b 97 46 21 16 21 69 c7 15 38 a5 39 37 2e 27 f3 f5 1d f3 b0 8b 2e 
11 1c 2d 6b bf 9f 58 87 f1 3a 8d b4 f1 eb 6d fe 38 6c 92 25 68 75 21 2d 
dd 00 46 87 85 c1 8a 9c 96 a2 92 b0 67 dd c7 1d a0 d5 64 00 0b 8b fd 80 
fb 14 c1 b5 67 44 a3 b5 c6 52 e8 ca 0e f0 b6 fd a6 4a ba 47 e3 a4 e8 94 
23 c0 21 2c 07 e3 9a 57 03 fd 46 75 40 f8 74 98 7b 20 95 13 42 9a 90 b0 
9b 04 97 03 d5 4d 9a 1c fe 3e 20 7e 0e 69 78 59 69 ca 5b f5 47 a3 6b a3 
4d 7c 6a ef e7 9f 31 4e 07 d9 f9 f2 dd 27 b7 29 83 ac 14 f1 46 67 54 cd 
41 26 25 16 e4 a1 5a b1 cf b6 22 e6 51 d3 e8 3f a0 95 da 63 0b d6 d9 3e 
97 b0 c8 22 a5 eb 42 12 d4 28 30 02 78 ce 6b a0 cc 74 90 b8 54 58 1f 0f 
fb 4b a3 d4 23 65 34 de 09 45 99 42 ef 11 5f aa 23 1b 15 15 3d 67 83 7a 
63 02 03 01 00 01
```

From [RFC3447 - Public-Key Cryptography Standards (PKCS) #1: RSA Cryptography Specifications Version 2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#page-44):

> **A.1.1 RSA public key syntax**
>
> An RSA public key should be represented with the ASN.1 type `RSAPublicKey`:
>
> ```
>   RSAPublicKey ::= SEQUENCE {
>      modulus           INTEGER,  -- n
>      publicExponent    INTEGER   -- e
>   }
> ```
>
> The fields of type RSAPublicKey have the following meanings:
>
> - modulus is the RSA modulus n.
> - publicExponent is the RSA public exponent e.

[Using Microsoft's excellent (and the only real) ASN.1 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb648645%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
30 82 01 0a       ;SEQUENCE (0x010A bytes: 266 bytes)
|  02 82 01 01    ;INTEGER  (0x0101 bytes: 257 bytes)
|  |  00          ;leading zero because high-bit, but number is positive
|  |  fb 11 99 ff 07 33 f6 e8 05 a4 fd 3b 36 ca 68 
|  |  e9 4d 7b 97 46 21 16 21 69 c7 15 38 a5 39 37 2e 27 f3 f5 1d f3 b0 8b 2e 
|  |  11 1c 2d 6b bf 9f 58 87 f1 3a 8d b4 f1 eb 6d fe 38 6c 92 25 68 75 21 2d 
|  |  dd 00 46 87 85 c1 8a 9c 96 a2 92 b0 67 dd c7 1d a0 d5 64 00 0b 8b fd 80 
|  |  fb 14 c1 b5 67 44 a3 b5 c6 52 e8 ca 0e f0 b6 fd a6 4a ba 47 e3 a4 e8 94 
|  |  23 c0 21 2c 07 e3 9a 57 03 fd 46 75 40 f8 74 98 7b 20 95 13 42 9a 90 b0 
|  |  9b 04 97 03 d5 4d 9a 1c fe 3e 20 7e 0e 69 78 59 69 ca 5b f5 47 a3 6b a3 
|  |  4d 7c 6a ef e7 9f 31 4e 07 d9 f9 f2 dd 27 b7 29 83 ac 14 f1 46 67 54 cd 
|  |  41 26 25 16 e4 a1 5a b1 cf b6 22 e6 51 d3 e8 3f a0 95 da 63 0b d6 d9 3e 
|  |  97 b0 c8 22 a5 eb 42 12 d4 28 30 02 78 ce 6b a0 cc 74 90 b8 54 58 1f 0f 
|  |  fb 4b a3 d4 23 65 34 de 09 45 99 42 ef 11 5f aa 23 1b 15 15 3d 67 83 7a 
|  |  63 
|  02 03          ;INTEGER (3 bytes)
|     01 00 01
```

giving the public key modulus and exponent:

- **modulus** = `0xfb1199ff0733f6e805a4fd3b36ca68...837a63`
- **exponent** = 65,537

---

**Update**: My [expanded form of this answer in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13104466/12597)

Comment: `RSA PUBLIC KEY` follows the ASN.1 form (see PKCS spec), it has nothing to do with OpenSSH's format.

Comment: Great answer - thanks so much.  The "leading zero because high-bit but number is positive" makes it in to the ssh-rsa key format according to the source.  The most useful hint about this I can find is a comment in github.com/openssh/openssh-portable which says "/* If MSB is set, prepend a \0 */" when writing out bignums in the ssh-rsa format.  This only appears to be a problem for the public modulus 50% (?) of the time and never in the public exponent due to the nature of the generated RSA keys.

Comment: great answer, about `string` and `mpint`  - it described in RFC 4251, section 5, no need to quess :)

Answer (score 26):

Reference Decoder of [CRL,CRT,CSR,NEW CSR,PRIVATE KEY, PUBLIC KEY,RSA,RSA Public Key Parser](https://8gwifi.org/PemParserFunctions.jsp)

RSA Public Key

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Encrypted Private Key

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

CRL

```
-----BEGIN X509 CRL-----
-----END X509 CRL-----
```

CRT

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

CSR

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

NEW CSR

```
-----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
-----END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

PEM

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

PKCS7

```
-----BEGIN PKCS7-----
-----END PKCS7-----
```

PRIVATE KEY

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

DSA KEY

```
-----BEGIN DSA PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END DSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Elliptic Curve

```
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

PGP Private Key

```
-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
-----END PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
```

PGP Public Key

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```