# Encryption using public-private keys

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

I've generated public-private keys using `ssh-keygen -t rsa`

Following is my public key

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDtbGPZjdnMWk8lJ/CdaBZROCtNk8H+Ru4keC7DK55q2t2ISRgjBaR4qZnWezAA2iJX3cwq2ulfwCPmyoc0G180lUEMDkZkeuWzyvwWjZIo0cehN2j28evgpZadfe+NxYYqQ2f7/3eJ+3IwT4EE6WmzaYjsYXloilJLVJFBbPkdy+1xnHAa1RXsdDNjMPQ9d9PSdr9BYlph21lzflk5wdBxXnLxzUD3mb3j0cCMrIl7IF2CbkKnBC4VFZahRRyJLBWvXvcxXR7Pspv6/WUE2GsZZ3GynAhS7LuHk7NKmB13+lQFejDGO4yVsXQLw7dg+JsIs4h3JkindgJRUytQq7lZ user@Ganesh-VirtualBox
```

This is my code which gets me the public key

```
public static PublicKey getPublicKey(String filename)
        throws Exception {

    File f = new File(filename);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[(int)f.length()];
    dis.readFully(keyBytes);
    dis.close();

    X509EncodedKeySpec spec =
            new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    return kf.generatePublic(spec);
}
```

I'm passing correct filename to this method. The line `kf.generatePublic(spec)` is throwing error as shown below.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format
at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:205)
at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:334)
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: SSH keys are not encoded in X509. See the answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749858/rsa-public-key-format.

Comment: Recent versions of OpenSSH should be able to output public key in "X.509" (really SPKI) PEM format with the strangely-named `ssh-keygen -e -m PKCS8`. Java can't handle PEM here, so either (1) delete the flag lines and convert the base64 to binary DER or (2) use `openssl rsa -pubin -in pemfile -out derfile -outform der`. Or, OpenSSH by default uses OpenSSL-compatible PEM format for *private* key, so given the private key `id_rsa` just do `openssl rsa -in id_rsa -pubout -out publicderfile -outform der`. In OpenSSL 1.0.0+ you can use `pkey` instead of `rsa`.

Answer (score 1):

Typically public keys are required in X.509 format and private keys are required in PKCS#8 format. So, whenever you are dealing with public/private keys, you need to make sure that they are in appropriate format.

Read below from [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/vstep2.html)

> So, first you need a key specification. You can obtain one via the
>   following, assuming that the **key was encoded according to the X.509
>   standard**, which is the case, for example, if the key was generated
>   with the built-in DSA key-pair generator supplied by the SUN provider:

Main error you are getting is `InvalidKeyException` which [says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/InvalidKeyException.html):

> This is the exception for invalid Keys (**invalid encoding**, wrong
>   length, uninitialized, etc).

Now in you case it is the invalid encoding which is resulting this error because you are using the generated public key in clear and not making it compatible with `X509EncodedKeySpec`. So, **to fix you problem first encode your public key as per X.509 standard so that you can use in `X509EncodedKeySpec`**