# Reading public key in Java

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

I read a lot of similar topics on SO but I am still a little bit confused.

I have a public key in **.pub** format (pure public key). The question is if it is possible to read it in this format in Java. I am able to read public key if it has **.der** format.

```
    RSAPublicKey publicKey
            = (RSAPublicKey) KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").
            generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(FileCopyUtils.
                    copyToByteArray(resource.getInputStream())));
```

Works fine. 
However it is not working for **.pub** format. If the only option is to read **der** file how should I correctly convert **.pub** to **.der**.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: See [RSA Public Key format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749858/rsa-public-key-format)

Comment: @Robert Thank you for the link - I read it before. I understand that there are differences in these formats. My question is if it is possible to load public key in pub format in java or if there some tools /libs to transform from pub to der.

Comment: Just ignore the text header and read only the base64 encoded part. Apply Base64Decode and you should have the DER form.

Comment: @Robert Thank you very much :) I will extend my question with code in Java including your advice in free time.